# Missing trailing-' in remote-shell command

Tags: bash, shell, rsync

In my bash shell scripting,

`rsync -a --delete -e "ssh -i /keypath" /source_dir/ username@remotehost:/dest_dir/`

whatever combinations [eval, double to single quotes] of above gives below err,

Missing trailing-' in remote-shell command.
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at ../main.c(335) [sender=2.6.8]

But the same command in directly working in command prompt.
Could anyone help in what im missing here

Thanks

Comment: Not enough information to be sure.  Try running `rsync -v -v -v`, which will print out, as the first line of debugging output, the actual shell command that's being run on the remote server.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is with embedded quotes in the bash script.

[Bash FAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

See the following solution (and upvote it if you find it useful, please):

https://superuser.com/questions/354361/rsync-complaining-about-missing-trailing-in-a-bash-script

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your problem is but for me most of weird rsync errors are caused by the `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` (or other shell rc files) outputting something when logging in. For now I usually write the following statement as the **first** line in my `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`:

```
# return if it's not an interactive shell
[[ $- == *i* ]] || return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution that worked for me is using **single** quotes instead of **double** quotes, i.e.

```
rsync -a --delete -e 'ssh -i /keypath' /source_dir/ username@remotehost:/dest_dir/
```